# Calculating the difference between two times of the day with an HTML form and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, time, difference

I'm trying to create an HTML form that takes in two times of the day as input 
(must include am/pm, cannot be military time), uses a JavaScript function to calculate the difference between these two times and outputs the difference to the screen.

For example, I type 1:15 pm (future time) and 12:00 am (current time) into an HTML form and the output to the screen is:

> 1:15 pm is 1 hour and 15 minutes away from 12:00 am.

I've got this working for military time, but cannot seem to figure out how to get the computer to recognize the value of am and pm, so if you do not know the answer to the entire problem, any ideas on how to solve this specific part of it would be a lot of help as well.

This is what I have for calculating the difference between times in military time:

Feel free to give me advice outside the domain of this question, I'm new to programming and if there is any thing questionable about my code (structure, readability, variable names, etc.) I would appreciate suggestions on how to improve it.

Thank you all!

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Calculate Time Difference </title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
  function calculateTimeDifference() {
    let input_CurrentTime = document.getElementById( "currentTime" );
    let input_FutureTime = document.getElementById( "futureTime" );
    let output_Difference = document.getElementById( "difference" );

    let currentTime = input_CurrentTime.value;
    if ( currentTime.includes( ":" ) ) {
      currentTime = currentTime.replace( ":". "" );
    }

    let futureTime = input_FutureTime
    if ( futureTime.includes( ":" ) ) {
      futureTime = futureTime.replace( ":", "" );
    }

    differenceEquation = futureTime - currentTime;
    output_Difference.value = futureTime + " is " + differenceEquation + " 
    away from " + currentTime;                                 
  }
</script>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "textBoxes.css"/>
```

```
<h1> Caclulate Time Difference </h1>

<form action = "/">

    <fieldset>
        <label> Current Time: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "currentTime"/>

        <label> Future Time: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "futureTime"/>
            <input type = "button" value = "click me" onclick = "calculateTimeDifference()"/>

        <label> Time Difference: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "difference"/>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: use Date object -

Comment: Can you provide your code on  what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it working for military time, then you can convert the AM/PM times to military time and then use whatever you used for military time.

- If it has "AM", then remove the AM and it's in military time
- If it has "PM", then remove the PM and add 12 and it's in military time (you'll have to "mod 24" the sum because if it's 12 PM, then 24 o'clock is not proper military time but 0 o'clock is).

Here's how you could convert from AM/PM to military time, so that you can apply the logic you have for military time to AM/PM strings.

```
    var time = "1:15 pm";
    if (time.includes("pm")) {
        time = time.replace("pm",""); //remove the "pm" from the string since military time doesn't have that.
        var colon = time.indexOf(":"); //get the position of the colon so we can get the hours before the colon
        var hours = time.substring(0,colon);
        hours = parseInt(hours);
        hours = (12 + hours) % 24; //add the 12 and mod it in case it's 24 o'clock
        time = hours + ":" + time.substring(colon + 1, time.length);    
    } else {
        time = time.replace("am",""); //if it doesn't have pm then remove am and leave it since this is already military time
    }
```

Comment: When I put this code in a function and tried passing in "1:15 pm", it returned 13: -1. I'm new to programming, and I'll be frank and just say I don't know what that means and when I try to pass in two numbers and subtract them, I just get NaN. I'm sorry hahah I should have specified my limited knowledge in my post.

Comment: I used ``time.indexOf`` instead of ``time.substring`` in the last line of the if statement by accident, it should work now!